# Invalid parameter number given with pdo's prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, laravel-4

Hello I have made a query to select certain values from the database. Unfortunately I am getting this error message: Invalid parameter number

[image]

The code is as followes

```
$vehicles = DB::select( DB::raw("
        SELECT v.id, v.brand, v.type, v.description, v.airco, v.seats, v.hourly_rent 
        FROM vehicle as v 
        WHERE v.id 
        NOT IN((SELECT v.id FROM vehicle as v INNER JOIN reservation as r on r.`vehicle_id` = v.id WHERE r.status_id in(3,4,5) 
        AND (
                (
                    (:start >= r.startdate AND :eind <= r.enddate )
                    OR
                    (:start <= r.startdate AND :eind >= r.enddate ) 
                ) 
                OR
                (
                    (:start >= r.startdate AND :start <= r.enddate)
                    OR
                    (:eind >= r.startdate AND :eind <= r.enddate)
                )
            )
        GROUP BY v.id
        ))"), 
         array(
            'start' => $startdate, 
            'eind' => $enddate
         )
    );
```

Comment: Can one use the same parameter name multiple times? I guess that's your problem.

Comment: So how do I solve this? Because as u see I have to match them up against each other..

Comment: Use different parameter names each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same parameter name multiple times. Give each parameter its own name and bind exactly that number of parameters:

```
$vehicles = DB::select( DB::raw("
        SELECT v.id, v.brand, v.type, v.description, v.airco, v.seats, v.hourly_rent 
        FROM vehicle as v 
        WHERE v.id 
        NOT IN((SELECT v.id FROM vehicle as v INNER JOIN reservation as r on r.`vehicle_id` = v.id WHERE r.status_id in(3,4,5) 
        AND (
                (
                    (:starta >= r.startdate AND :einda <= r.enddate )
                    OR
                    (:startb <= r.startdate AND :eindb >= r.enddate ) 
                ) 
                OR
                (
                    (:startc >= r.startdate AND :startd <= r.enddate)
                    OR
                    (:eindc >= r.startdate AND :eindd <= r.enddate)
                )
            )
        GROUP BY v.id
        ))"), 
         array(
            'starta' => $startdate, 
            'einda' => $enddate,
            'startb' => $startdate, 
            'eindb' => $enddate,
            'startc' => $startdate, 
            'eindc' => $enddate,
            'startd' => $startdate, 
            'eindd' => $enddate
         )
    );
```

Comment: Hi Marcel, do you know why this is so? Why can't binding names be used more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You actually can. Just leave PDO in emulation mode.

Comment: If you want maximum security, you don't want PDO to be in emulation mode, but using *real* prepared statements.

Comment: There is no difference, security is equal.

Comment: Remember http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/258127? (I admit it's an edge case, but it *is* more dangerous to use PDO in emulation mode).

Comment: there is not single problem with this case.